# gmaps4rails - Existing marker doesn't get cleared when dropping a new marker in the form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, google-maps, gmaps4rails

I have a Rails 3.2 app that allows a user to create a shop and I want the user to put their shop on the map. I tried the [gmaps4rails](https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails/) gem & got it to work by using the default configuration — converting the address input by the user to coordinates & show the marker on the map. However I find the conversion process inconsistent in accuracy & I prefer to let the user to drop their own marker on the map.

This is my code after following the gem's readme:

```
# migration
t.string  "address",  :null => false
t.float   "latitude"
t.float   "longitude"
t.boolean "gmaps"

# model Shop.rb
attr_accessible :name, :address, :latitude, :longitude

acts_as_gmappable

def gmaps4rails_address
  address
end

# shops_controller.rb
def show
  @shop = Shop.find(params[:id])
  @json = Shop.all.to_gmaps4rails
end

def edit
  @shop = Shop.find(params[:id])
  @json = Shop.all.to_gmaps4rails
end

def update
  @shop = Shop.find(params[:id])
  @json = Shop.all.to_gmaps4rails

  if @shop.update_attributes(params[:shop])
    flash[:success] = "Shop's updated."
    redirect_to shop_path(@shop)
  end
end

# view
<%= gmaps4rails(@json) %>
```

The form partial (referenced from the gem's [wiki](https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails/wiki/Javascript-goodies)):

```
# _form.html.erb
....
<%= gmaps4rails(@json) %>
<% content_for :scripts do %>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
  var markersArray = [];
  // On click, clear markers, place a new one, update coordinates in the form
  Gmaps.map.callback = function() {
    google.maps.event.addListener(Gmaps.map.serviceObject, 'click', function(event) {
      clearOverlays();
      placeMarker(event.latLng);
      updateFormLocation(event.latLng);
    });
  };
  // Update form attributes with given coordinates
  function updateFormLocation(latLng) {
    $('#shop_attributes_latitude').val(latLng.lat());
    $('#shop_attributes_longitude').val(latLng.lng());
    $('#shop_attributes_gmaps_zoom').val(Gmaps.map.serviceObject.getZoom());
  }
  // Add a marker with an open infowindow
  function placeMarker(latLng) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latLng, 
        map: Gmaps.map.serviceObject,
        draggable: true
    });
    markersArray.push(marker);
    // Set and open infowindow
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: '<div class="popup"><h2>Awesome!</h2><p>Drag me and adjust the zoom level.</p>'
    });
    infowindow.open(Gmaps.map.serviceObject,marker);
    // Listen to drag & drop
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function() {
        updateFormLocation(this.getPosition());
    });
  }
  // Removes the overlays from the map
  function clearOverlays() {
    if (markersArray) {
      for (var i = 0; i < markersArray.length; i++ ) {
        markersArray[i].setMap(null);
      }
    }
    markersArray.length = 0;
  }
</script>
```

Problems:

- When clicked on the map, the existing marker doesn't get cleared. It does give a new marker though.
- When I click the submit button, the latitude & longitude are not updated to reflect the new position of the new marker. It just use the old one.

---

**UPDATE**

I managed to get the "update the marker position" part working but the existing marker still not cleared when map was clicked in the form. The result on the show page only shows the updated marker, which is nice.

Here's the updated code:

```
# Shop.rb
acts_as_gmappable :process_geocoding => false

# no more def gmaps4rails_address in the model

# controller
def show
  @json = Shop.find(params[:id]).to_gmaps4rails
end

def edit
  @json = Shop.find(params[:id]).to_gmaps4rails
end

def update
  @shop = Shop.find(params[:id])
  # @json = Shop.all.to_gmaps4rails # not needed here
  ...
end

# _form.html.erb
<%= gmaps4rails(@json) %>
<%= f.hidden_field :latitude %>
<%= f.hidden_field :longitude %>
<% content_for :scripts do %>
...
function updateFormLocation(latLng) {
  $('#shop_latitude').val(latLng.lat());
  $('#shop_longitude').val(latLng.lng());
  $('#shop_gmaps_zoom').val(Gmaps.map.serviceObject.getZoom());
}
...
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you should simply replace:

```
markersArray[i].setMap(null);
```

With:

```
markersArray[i].serviceObject.setMap(null);
```

Comment: With `markersArray[i].setMap(null);` — When I go to the edit form in the browser, it shows me the current marker. Clicking the map gives me a new marker but doesn't delete the old one. Clicking for the second time on the map replaces the 'new' marker but still doesn't delete the 'old' one. However with `markersArray[i].serviceObject.setMap(null);` it disables clicking the map for the second time to clear the 'new' marker.

Comment: I'm currently rewriting the js part of the gem, I should clarify many things.

Comment: @apneadiving did this problem get solved in the end? I'm stuck in the same situation. Thanks